# Ошибка: Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

С чем может связана ошибка:

> Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто
>   свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.

Написан проект на c# и dll на c++, по отдельности компилируется без ошибок, но когда запускаешь проект, доходит до второй функции (написанной в dll)  и выдает эту ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

Это означает что вы пытаетесь писать или читать по адресу памяти, который не принадлежит вашей программе. Например, вы можете писать или читать память за пределами динамически выделенного массива, или обращаться к памяти по null-указателю.

То, что программа компилируется, не означает, что она корректная.

Comment: "или обращаться к памяти по null-указателю" - в большинстве случаев там такой ошибки не будет. По крайней мере, в шарпе.

Comment: @Qwertiy Как я понял, ошибка возникает при вызове C++ функции из dll.

Comment: Но ведь шарп разворачивает обращения по адресам меньше 65К в NullReferenceException, а большие сыплятся с access violation. Разве ситуация изменится, если соответствующее обращение произойдёт в коде на плюсах?

Comment: @Qwertiy Откуда вы знаете, что делается в функции на C++? Может быть там имеет место попытка изменить строковый литерал, или происходит выделение памяти, или происходит сравнение строк с использованием null-указателя или происходит некорректный вызов Windows API.

Comment: Я имел в виду ситуацию: код на си++ обращается по нулевому указателю (ну где-то рядом). Неужели вызывающий код на шарпе не превратит это в NullReferenceException в соответствии со своими правилами? Откуда теперь появилось про некорректный вызов или изменение readony - я же с этим не спорил.

Comment: @Qwertiy Откуда вы и вызывающий код знает, что делает C++ функция?

Comment: А откуда он в шарпе знает? Там разве не прерывание происходит, при доступе к защищённой памяти?

Comment: @Qwertiy Во-первых, программа может выполняться в режиме debug, где результат выполнения перехватывается. Вам интересно тратить свое и чужое время на гадание?

Comment: У меня нет оснований считать, что вызванный плюсовой код и любой другой код будут обработаны по-разному.

Comment: @Qwertiy Где говорится о том, что что-то будет обработано по-разному? Речь идет о том, что может стать причиной подобного сообщения.

Comment: Ну так если может, то это будет означать разную обработку, а это странно.